# XMLStarlet does not return any value with xpath query input

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, xmlstarlet

I am trying to query the value of a certain attribute in my given xml file. In different other test-tools i checked the query and it returned the expected value "OPEN" but trying this with the xmlstartlet command line tool, it does not work. It just returns nothin.

Here is the command which i tried

```
xml.exe sel -N ns3=urn:de.srs.pen.virtual.request -t -v "/ns3:penrequest/attributes/attribute[@module="MobileClearance"]/@value" ..\data\DE_OJ_PortalPrint-.480328.xml
```

There is no return value or message, the errorcode of this is 1 which indicates a false execution. Am I using a xpath command which xmlstarlet does not understand?

Here the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns3:penrequest clientid="PDiX API V4.1.4-SNAPSHOT0" creator="OJ/user001" formid="DE_OJ_PortalPrint" instanceid="TEST.OPEN.480369" lastupdate="2016-06-08T09:25:38.983Z" pageid="" patternid="" pduser="OJ/Oliver" penid="SRS-000-IJ0-B1" start="2016-06-08T11:25:29.623+02:00" stop="2016-05-18T07:52:23.534+02:00" transmission="2016-06-08T11:28:50.926+02:00" updates="2" xmlns:ns2="urn:srs.pdx.metadata" xmlns:ns3="urn:de.srs.pen.virtual.request" xmlns:ns4="urn:srs.pdx.servicelist" xmlns:ns5="urn:srs.pdx.metaxaconfig" xmlns:ns6="http://verification.ws.pen.srs.de/">
<sessions>
    <session created="2016-06-08T09:25:30.560Z" datahash="bc1684ea5cbb4e65e745a640b056b1582e0dc0fc" device="SRS-000-IJ0-3H" extended="0" finished="2016-06-08T09:25:38.923Z" firstProcessed="2016-06-08T09:25:38.923Z" lastProcessed="2016-06-08T09:25:38.953Z" lastupdate="2016-06-08T09:25:38.953Z" order="2" sourcetype="VP" user="OJ/user001"/>
    <session created="2016-06-08T09:25:29.623Z" datahash="1e75a13b5287a638c1ad1fc2c3b02c8402e47170" device="SRS-000-IJ0-3H" extended="0" finished="2016-06-08T09:25:29.623Z" firstProcessed="2016-06-08T09:25:29.623Z" lastProcessed="2016-06-08T09:25:29.733Z" lastupdate="2016-06-08T09:25:29.780Z" order="1" sourcetype="VP" user="OJ/user001"/>
</sessions>
<formfields>
    <field device="SRS-000-IJ0-3H" fieldtype="EF" fullname="textfield" group="" icrconfidence="0" icrrecognition="0" key="textfield" lastupdate="2016-06-08T09:25:38.983Z" pageid="" sessionid="2" sourcetype="VP" start="2016-06-08T09:25:30.560Z" stop="2016-06-08T11:25:38.923+02:00" updateid="2" user="OJ/user001" value="Offene Instanz">
        <details>
            <detail end="2016-06-08T11:25:38.923+02:00" lastupdate="2016-06-08T09:25:38.983Z" session="2" start="2016-06-08T09:25:30.560Z" user="OJ/user001" value="Offene Instanz"/>
        </details>
        <attributes/>
    </field>
</formfields>
<attributes>
    <attribute device="SRS-SYS-TEM-VP" lastupdate="2016-06-08T09:25:46.223Z" module="Renderer" name="engine" user="SYSTEM/system" value="TBS.RenderingThread-Renderernull"/>
    <attribute device="SRS-SYS-TEM-VP" lastupdate="2016-06-08T09:25:53.367Z" module="Renderer" name="state" user="SYSTEM/system" value="OK"/>
    <attribute device="SRS-000-IJ0-3H" lastupdate="2016-06-08T09:25:39.077Z" module="CradleASH" name="Checksum" user="OJ/user001" value="null"/>
    <attribute device="SRS-000-IJ0-3H" lastupdate="2016-06-08T09:25:29.907Z" module="MobileClearance" name="state" user="OJ/user001" value="OPEN"/>
    <attribute device="SRS-000-IJ0-3H" lastupdate="2016-06-08T09:25:39.030Z" module="CradleASH" name="ClientId" user="OJ/user001" value="V4.1.4-SNAPSHOT0192.168.102.121 - 192.168.102.121 - OJ/user001"/>
</attributes>
<attachments>
    <binary created="2016-06-08T09:25:46.613Z" device="SRS-SYS-TEM-VP" filename="virtual-bg-input.xml" lastupdate="2016-06-08T09:25:46.613Z" name="srs.vp-renderer.xml" page="1" pageidx="0" rectime="2016-06-08T09:25:46.613Z" rectimestop="2016-06-08T09:25:46.613Z" source="XX" type="application/xml" user="SYSTEM/system">
        <data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
    </binary>
</attachments>
```

Comment: Do you get the right result if you use different quote delimiters inside the XPath expression, as in `"/ns3:penrequest/attributes/attribute[@module='MobileClearance']/@value"`?

Comment: yes this works (FACEPALM) thanks